# Android: Changing targetSdkVersion from 15 to 18 effects the layout view

Tags: java, android

Changing the TargetSdk version in the Android Manifest.xml file from 15 to 18 affects the height of the `Linearlayout`. Actually the height of the `Linearlayout` is getting increased with the change of TargetSdk.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
 android:paddingTop="3dp"
 android:layout_margin="0dp"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
android:orientation="horizontal"  
 android:background="@drawable/border">

     <ImageButton 
    android:clickable="true"            
    android:id="@+id/f_rewards"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="center" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
     android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:background="@drawable/border_left_footer"
    android:src="@drawable/rewards_f"        
    />    

     <ImageButton 
          android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/f_scan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="center" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
     android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_weight=".33"
      android:background="@drawable/border_left_footer"
    android:src="@drawable/scan_f"        
    />    


       <ImageButton 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/f_check_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="center" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:layout_margin="0dp" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_weight=".33"       
    android:background="@drawable/border_left_footer"

    android:src="@drawable/check_in_f"        
    />    


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, and what is the question/problem?

Comment: Layout Height is android:layout_height="wrap_content" in the Linear Layout but when in SDK Version 18 . Height of the Linear Layout increases to Double of what it appears in Target Version 15

Comment: Since it's `wrap_content`, the height is really dictated by the imagebutton drawables. Is there any variation in those?

Comment: what is the solution??

Comment: We have all the version of the image i.e mdpi, xhdi, ldpi but the image size is fine i guess padding or some margin is being added or something. but i dont see any such issues should come up through the code. And the major thing is if SDK Version is 15 its perfectly fine but for SDK Version 18 there is too much of Margin / Padding

Answer (score 0):

okay, ive found the solution, the solution was to remove " android:adjustViewBounds="true" from ImageButton and it works :) The new xml would be this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"  
android:layout_margin="0dp"  
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"      
android:background="@drawable/border">

     <ImageButton 
    android:clickable="true"            
    android:id="@+id/f_rewards"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="center"       
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="10dp"       
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:background="@drawable/border_left_footer"
    android:src="@drawable/rewards_f"        
    />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/f_scan"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="0dp"
         android:layout_weight=".33"            
         android:background="@drawable/border_left_footer"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:scaleType="center"
         android:src="@drawable/scan_f" />

       <ImageButton 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/f_check_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="center"        
    android:layout_margin="0dp" 
    android:padding="10dp"

    android:layout_weight=".33"       
    android:background="@drawable/border_left_footer"

    android:src="@drawable/check_in_f"        
    />    


</LinearLayout>
```